# Razor default selection in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following declaration in Razor:

`@Html.DropDownList("SelectedRole", ViewBag.RolesEdit as List<SelectListItem>, ViewBag.CurrentUserRole as string, new { @class = "form-control" })`, and it results in a drop-down that looks as follows on page load:

[image]

And when I click on the dropdown arrow, I see:

[image]

So basically, the User Role is duplicated. How can I change this so that instead of making a new duplicate element, it defaults to the element it is supposed to be? Basically, since `ViewBag.RolesEdit` is a list, and `ViewBag.CurrentUserRole` is guaranteed to have an element that is equal to exactly one item in the afformentioned list, how can I loop through the list to compare each other and set the default?

Thank You.

Comment: You might want to look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37819577/296861).

Comment: Is `CurrentUserRole` set to the `text` `RegularUser` or is set to the `value` corresponding to `RegularUser`?

Comment: @stephen.vakil it is set to the `text` in the controller as follows: `ViewBag.CurrentUserRole = user.UserRole();` where `user` is a type of user from the Identity framework.

Comment: @Win I will keep it in mind when it comes time to refactor the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Html.DropDownList` helper method, To set one option to be pre selected, you just need to set the **value** of that option to the the ViewBag dictionary with the same key used to generate the SELECT element.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedRole", ViewBag.RolesEdit as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Assuming your action method is setting `ViewBag.SelectedRole` to the `value` of the option you want to select.

```
ViewBag.RolesEdit= new List<SelectListItem>{     
   new SelectListItem { Value="Administrator", Text="Administrator"},
   new SelectListItem { Value="Employees", Text="Employees"},
   new SelectListItem { Value="RegularUser", Text="Regular User"},
}
ViewBag.SelectedRole  ="RegularUser";
return View();
```

If you prefer to use `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method with a strongly typed view and view model, you can follow this post

[What is the best ways to bind @Html.DropDownListFor in ASP.NET MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550804/what-is-the-best-ways-to-bind-html-dropdownlistfor-in-asp-net-mvc5)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I used `ViewBag.SelectedRole = user.UserRole();` instead of the hardcoding it as in your answer.