# ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor with model of type Ienumerable<model>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to bind  IEnumerable model to DropDownListFor and DropDownList
    @model IEnumerable
    @Html.DropDownListFor();

Comment: have a view model which has one property for the collection and one to hold the selected value. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550804/what-is-the-best-ways-to-bind-html-dropdownlistfor-in-asp-net-mvc5) is some sample code

Comment: then tell me how could i get

Comment: See the link i posted in the prev comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 View
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.doc_typeid, Model.doctype_name, "--Select--", new {    @class = "form-control", @style="width:auto;" })
 Controller
 var docTypes = from c in db.tm_doc_type select c;
 doctype_name = new SelectList(docTypes, "doc_typeid", "doctype_name"),
```